# C# How To Increment/Decrement A Label?

Tags: c#, forms, increment

I'm trying to do a simple guess the number game but in a form, the problem is when I click btnGuess the score goes up even if it's blank despite the comparing logic. If I remove the guessCount at line 59 and lblguessCount.Text = guessCount.ToString(); it simply goes down in negatives. Even if the number is a correct guess if its negative or a positive number it doesn't change...

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Guess_The_Number_V2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int score = 0;
        private int randNum;
        private int guess = 0;
        private int guessCount = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void lblGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbldebug.Text = randNum.ToString();
            Random rand = new Random();
            randNum = rand.Next(0, 10);
        }

        private void txtGuess_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            guess = Convert.ToInt32(txtGuess.Text);
        }


        private void btnGuess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {

                if (guess == randNum)
                {
                    score += 1;
                    lblScore.Text = score.ToString();

                }
                else if (guess != randNum)
                {
                    score-=1;
                    lblScore.Text = score.ToString();
                }

                guessCount++;
                lblguessCount.Text = guessCount.ToString();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code. You should not generate a new `Random` each time you click the button. You should create a class-level `Random` variable and set it to a `new Random()` by default (once).

You are also setting the lblDebug.Text to the value of `randNum` *before* you change the value. This means it is always showing the previous random number, not the current one. To fix this, just put the assignment of the `Text` property after the assignment of `randNum`.

Also, your code in the `btnGuess_Click` method will subtract one from their score every time they get an incorrect guess. Probably we should ignore incorrect guesses and just give them a minimum number of tries instead.

Mostly, though, the code feels like it was written without a proper design (sorry if I'm wrong about that). What I usually do is first write out the scenario, then write pseudo-code that I'd *like* my final code to look like, and finally implement that in real code.

For example:

> Scenario: 
> 1. Form Loads. 
> 2. Random number is chosen between 1 and 100. 
> 3. User is notified that they have 15 tries to guess the number. 
> 4. User enters a number in a text box and presses a button
> 5. If the number matches, congratulate them and reset the game (back to step #2)
> 6. If the number is incorrect, tell them if they were too low or two high, and go to step 4.
> 7. If the user has no guesses left, let them know what the number was and reset the game.

The code I'd like to write would look something like:

- In Form Load we would call a `ResetGame` method
- In the ResetGame method we would reset the number of guesses, choose a random number, and put up a message box with instructions
- In the Button Click event we call a method called `CheckForWinner`
- In the `CheckForWinner` method, we see they entered a valid number

  - If they didn't show a message indicating that they need to correct their guess
  - If they did, see if the number matches our random number
  - If it does, show a message to the user and then call `ResetGame`
  - If it doesn't, call a method `DisplayHighLowMessage`
  - Also if it doesn't, we call a method `FinalizeTurn`
- In the `DisplayHighLowMessage` method, we compare the number to the random number and display a message indicating if it was too low or too high
- In the `FinalizeTurn` method, we increment the guess count, and see if it's more than the maximum

  - If it's greater than the maximum guess count, let the user know the game is over, show them the number, and call `ResetGame`

Now that I have a general idea of the program flow and the methods I'd need to create, we can create them. We know we'll need class-level variables to store the number of guesses, the current score, the current guess, and the random number. We'll also want a class-level `Random` variable since it only needs to be initialized once.

Here's how the code would look:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int score;
    private int randNum;
    private int guess;
    private int guessCount;
    private const int MaxGuesses = 15;
    private readonly Random rnd = new Random();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ResetGame();
    }

    private void ResetGame()
    {
        // Choose new random number
        randNum = rnd.Next(1, 101);
        lblDebug.Text = randNum.ToString();

        // Reset variables
        guessCount = 0;
        lblGuessCount.Text = guessCount.ToString();
        txtGuess.Text = "";

        // Show instructions
        MessageBox.Show("I've chosen a random number from 1 to 100." +
            $" You have {MaxGuesses} tries to guess it!");
    }

    private void btnGuess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckForWinner();
    }

    private void CheckForWinner()
    {
        if (guess == randNum)
        {
            // Increment the score
            score += 1;
            lblScore.Text = score.ToString();

            // Tell user they won, and reset game
            MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! You guessed" +
                $" the number in {guessCount} tries!");

            ResetGame();
        }
        else
        {
            // Tell them if they're too high or low, and finish this turn
            DisplayHighLowMessage();
            FinalizeTurn();
        }
    }

    private void DisplayHighLowMessage()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(guess < randNum
            ? "That guess is too low!"
            : "That guess is too high!");
    }

    private void FinalizeTurn()
    {
        // Increment guess count
        guessCount++;
        lblGuessCount.Text = guessCount.ToString();

        // If they've used all their guesses, show them the number and reset the game
        if (guessCount > MaxGuesses)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Sorry, you're out of guesses! The number was: {randNum}.");
            ResetGame();
        }
    }

    private void txtGuess_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // If the textbox is being cleared, allow it and reset the guess.
        if (txtGuess.Text == "")
        {
            guess = 0;
        }
        // Otherwise, use int.TryParse in case the 'Text' property 
        // doesn't contian a valid number. The code below says, 
        // "if TryParse succeeds, update our guess with the new number"
        int newGuess;
        if (int.TryParse(txtGuess.Text, out newGuess))
        {
            guess = newGuess;
        }

        // Ensure our textbox is displaying the current value of 'guess'
        txtGuess.Text = guess.ToString();
        txtGuess.SelectionStart = txtGuess.TextLength;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point, I did want to make the number generate after guessing. I wanted to show the generated number for debug purposed thank you for noticing it wasn't implemented correctly. I will use and make more methods which is much better practice to do. I'll use your code but not copy and paste if you know what I mean.
I really wish I could find a proper good tutorial on classes and how to use them properly every tutorial just confuses me. And your right sadly I didn't think it through, I kept adding in things before thinking of how I would need to implement them correctly.

Comment: I am curious I know this
            MessageBox.Show(guess < randNum
                ? "That guess is too low!"
                : "That guess is too high");
Is rather new what is  it called? I know its  something to do with default values but I can't remember it's technical name.

Comment: The ternary operator `? :` is a simple `if/else`. If the condition before the `?` is true, then it returns the value after the `?`, otherwise it returns the value after the `:`.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void txtGuess_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(txtGuess.Text != null)
        guess = Convert.ToInt32(txtGuess.Text);
}

private void btnGuess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            if(guess <= 10 && guess >= 0)
            {
                if (guess == randNum)
                {
                    score += 1;
                    lblScore.Text = score.ToString();

                }
                else if (guess != randNum)
                {
                    score-=1;
                    lblScore.Text = score.ToString();
                }

                guessCount++;
                lblguessCount.Text = guessCount.ToString();
            }else{score -=1;}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that as well but I thought score -= would simple rewrite 1 or -1 to the variable. Sadly now the app simple goes into negative numbers no matter what

Comment: I added a bit more code to the answer, I have to leave work now. This code should get you started though. @LiamVallance

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that logic, though I have never used != before, it's still going negative but I  will have a look since I have to sleep. Cheers btw!

Comment: What variable is going into negative numbers? you can use the operator `>=` ex: `if(variable >= 0)`